# how to mask an incoming input string in C#

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

For instance:

```
string maskedString = MaskString("ABCDEFGHIJLK", 2, 3, 'X');
```

Output: `ABXXXXXXXJLK`

```
string maskedString = MaskString("123456", 2, 3, '*');
```

Output: `12*456`

```
string MaskString(string inputString, int leftUnMaskLength, int rightUnMaskLength, char maskCharacter)
{
    //What is the simplest way to code this efficiently in C# .Net 3.5
}
```

Comment: As it stands now this is perfectly answerable. (In VB.NET the `Mid` statement would solve the problem in one line.) Though I assume the second output should be `12*456`.

Comment: @Mark Hurd - reopened, feel free to answer (and possibly improve the question a bit more)

Comment: One suggestion I have is to change the signature to have 'MaskStartPosition' and 'MaskLength' -- instead of 'UnMaskLeft' and 'UnMaskRight'

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `String.Substring` method to grab the start and end part of the string, and use the `String` constructor to build the masked middle part. You'd get something like this then:

```
static string MaskString(string inputString, int leftUnMaskLength, int rightUnMaskLength, char mask)
{
    if ((leftUnMaskLength + rightUnMaskLength) > inputString.Length)
        return inputString;

    return inputString.Substring(0, leftUnMaskLength) +
        new string(mask, inputString.Length - (leftUnMaskLength + rightUnMaskLength)) + 
        inputString.Substring(inputString.Length - rightUnMaskLength);
}
```

Comment: +1 The OP did ask for an _efficient_ answer. BTW the body of my VB.NET "one-liner" is (inefficient because of Microsoft's implementation of the `Mid` statement) these three lines: `MaskString = inputString` : `Dim maskLength = inputString.Length - (leftUnMaskLength + rightUnMaskLength)` : `Mid(MaskString, leftUnMaskLength + 1, maskLength) = New String(mask, maskLength)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one implementation:

```
string MaskString(string inputString, int leftUnMaskLength, int rightUnMaskLength, char maskCharacter)
{
    var output = new List<char>();
    var inputLength = inputString.Length;
    for(var q = 0; q < inputLength; q++) 
    {
          if (q < leftUnMaskLength || q > (inputLength - (rightUnMaskLength + 1)))
          {
              output.Add(inputString[q]);
          }
          else
          {
              output.Add(maskCharacter);
          }
    }
    return new String(output.ToArray());
}
```